# bootstrap-vue's `b-tabs` renders differently depending on the Vue build that I import

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I'm using bootstrap-vue and I've noticed `b-tabs` renders differently depending on the Vue build that I import:

If I import  `vue` it renders correctly:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-77mzg

But if I import `vue/dist/vue.common` or `vue/dist/vue` It renders wrongly:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-y0t15

Also, it doesn't happen with other components, like `b-navbar-nav`. They render correctly regardless of the vue build I import.

I'd like to understand why does it happen, since I need to import a vue version that includes the compiler because some components need it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When importing a specific variant of Vue (i.e. commonjs vs ES), you need to set up an `alias` in webpack to ensure that BootstrapVue (and other dependants such as PortalVue) use the same build of Vue (as BootstrapVue also imports from `vue`).

See the docs on setting up aliases (so you can just `import Vue from 'vue'`):

https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs#aliasing-vue-import

i.e. for Webpack config

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you don't know how long I've been dealing with this issue and it was very easy to fix